# How do I solve the problem that the click event does not work when I leave a specific area in Swift's scrollview?

Tags: swift

I created a UIScrollView and made many uiViews in it horizontally
I set up touch events for each uiView and it works well.
However, when I scroll the ScrollView beyond a certain area, the uiView touch event does not work. When I scroll back to the very beginning area, the uiView there works with a touch event. What is the problem?
Below is part of the source

```
mainScrollView = UIScrollView()
mainScrollView.bounces = false
mainScrollView.backgroundColor = .white
mainScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
mainScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
mainScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
mainScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
mainScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vAds.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

let vBrod = UIView()
vBrod.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
vBrod.backgroundColor = .white
vBrod.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xa5a5a5).cgColor
vBrod.layer.borderWidth = BORDER_WIDTH

vBroadcast.addSubview(vBrod)
            
vBrod.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainScrollView.leadingAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
vBrod.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
vBrod.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: WIDTH).isActive = true
vBrod.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: HEIGHT).isActive = true
            
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonClicked))
vBrod.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
vBrod.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```